# Orchard's Web Request Workflow activity

Tags: orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I'm currently running Orchard v1.9.3, and I would like to use Orchard's web request workflow activity to make an API call to MailChimp's API (http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members). I was able to determine the value for the URL field should have the following form:

https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/My_MailChimp_list_id/members/

Since I'm saving data to my MailChimp list, I'm going to select "PUT" for the verb drop down field. Based on MailChimp's API documentation, I was going to enter the following value in the "Headers" field:
'content-type: application/json'

MailChimp expects a JSON-formatted request, so I'm going to choose "Json" in the "Form Format" drop-down field.

The part that I'm struggling with is the "Form Values" field. According to the API docs, the data should have the following format, "'{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}'". I know MailChimp expects my e-mail address in lieu of "urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", but I don't understand how to map the first name, last name, and email address values from my Orchard form into this Json request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you linked to, the API expects a POST request. But maybe it supports PUT all the same, I don't know.

Regarding your question, you can access the submitted FORM values via the following token:

`#FormSubmission.Field:MyFieldName`

So for example, if the Dynamic Forms field name you used is named **EmailAddress**, your JSON should look something like this:

`{
   "email_address":"#FormSubmission.Field:EmailAddress",
   "status":"subscribed"
}`

PS: Kudos for using Dynamic Forms and the Web Request Activity!